# What is the correct answer?

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

What is the correct answer ?

> He **is becoming** / **is going to become** a geologist when he leaves university. This is his plan.

Comment: Which do you think is the better option?

Comment: I like "He will become a geologist" best.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer of your two options would be

> "He is going to become a geologist when he leaves university. This is his plan.".

The below options would also work:

> *"His plan after leaving university is to become a geologist."*
>
> *"He plans to become a geologist when he leaves university."*

It's worth noting that although **to become** is technically the most correct verb in this case, **to be** would also be accepted as correct in all of these sentences as well.

Comment: Of your two alternate options, I really like the second one, but I have a hard time not cringing at the first.